# Using 'which' in relation to a sentence

Tags: pronoun

I have a sentence, as following:

> **Obwohl sie schikaniert wurden, hätten die jungen Kinder, mit denen ich
>    arbeite, freundlicher sein können, wenn sie mehr mit ihren
>    hilfsbereiten Eltern gesprochen hätten.**
>
> *Although they used to be bullied, the young children, with whom I work, could have been friendlier if they had spoken more to their helpful parents.*

But was unsure on how to say 'which' in relation to the sentence, as in:

> *Although they used to be bullied, the young children, with whom I work, could have been friendlier if they had spoken more to their helpful parents, **which I find sad***

Would you use:

> ... das ich traurig finde

Or is there another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case it must be

> ..., was ich traurig finde.

The reason is that there has not been an established entity to which the "das" could refer. Instead, you need a word that refers to the previously expressed fact AND establishes it as a constituent. That's when you need "was" (or the wo-words, same logic).
For a more detailed discussion take a loot at this article on [**my blog**](https://yourdailygerman.wordpress.com/2014/07/29/wo-compounds-worauf-woraus-wovon-meaning-german/) (second half).

Answer (score 0):

The relative pronoun "which" can be used with reference to a sentence. The corresponding German relative pronoun is "was". Example: Er ist arbeitslos, was ihm schwer zu schaffen macht." This might be derived from a second sentence: Das ist etwas, das ihm zu schaffen macht/ etwas, was ihm zu schaffen macht.